# Autodestroy React build

Tags: reactjs, build

I am experimenting with a react application that could be autodestroyed after a period of time. Let's say today is monday and once the react code is build(`npm run build`) and hosted, on Friday morning 6:00 a.m. the build files or parts of it should be auto-erased if someone tries to visit the deployed application through the URL. Note that the validations should happen inside the build files and not on the server codes. Is there a way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. React apps are built, then deployed. Unless the host machine is also doing the build, this makes no sense. If the host machine is also doing the build, it depends on how it's doing the build.